# how can I write on generic class for all Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

I want to write a one class generic for all Repository

I have a class Entity (Product,price,.... )

and the Interface  IRepository

```
 public  interface IRepository<T> 
    {
        Dictionary<int, T> myProduct { get; set; }

        IEnumerable<T> List { get; }
        void Add(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity,int key);
        void Update(T entity,int key);
        T FindById(int Id);

    }
```

I can write my Repository for each business object like ProudductRepository, priceReporsitory,.....

but I need to implements as a generic something like this

```
 public class Repository<E, C> : IRepository<E>
```

and I use this for all my business object not one foreach entity

Comment: OK,You can do that.Now what is your question ?

Comment: 'but I need to implements as a generic' -> why?

Comment: I know can do that but how

Comment: BTW if you're using this abstraction on top of Entity Framework, I'd personally recommend against it.  Generic Repositories and EF's Unit of Work tend to leave you with gaping holes in terms of functionality.

Comment: Yes I use the entity frame work already based on the repository .
but I need that for another part

Comment: http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as shown below.This is just an example.

**Create a Generic Repository**

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal SchoolContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

Please read more about it on [**Implement a Generic Repository and a Unit of Work Class**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) article.

*More Articles for you :*

[**Generic Repository and UnitofWork patterns in MVC**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825646/Generic-Repository-and-UnitofWork-patterns-in-MVC)

[**Generic Repository and Unit of Work Pattern**](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc)